# How do I send data to my ajax method from my controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to update a element based on things that are happening in the code server side.
For instance, when I invoke my "Start" function by clicking a button on my page it should change the text inside the element to "Downloading", and then once it's done it should change the text to "Done".

I have this script on my page which invokes a action and updates the text after making a successful request.

```
<script>
        function StartDownload() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Start", "MyPage")', success: function (result) {
                $("#badge").removeClass("badge-danger").addClass("badge-info").html("Downloading");
        }});
    };
</script>
```

as you can see, right now it's just making a request and on success it changes the class and it changes the text to "Downloading".

The goal is to change it to "Downloading" once it invokes the method, and then once the method finishes I want to change the text to "Done".

And I'm not sure how to do that, I need to some how listen for multiple calls in my ajax method but I have no idea how to do that.

What's the proper way of achieving this?

I was thinking of doing something like this but I'm not sure if that's valid

```
public ActionResult Start()
{
    //Post data back to the ajax to tell it to change to "Downloading"
    StartDownload();
    //Post data back to the ajax to tell it to change to "Finished"

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at SignalR.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple in fact.
Except `success` $.ajax() has a lot of other "events", which you can use.
`beforeSend` for example may be your choice, because it executes just before ajax call
You can find more events here:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/